# HOW TO SAVE DATA IN ORACALE 11G EXPRES EDITION COMMAND LINE?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus

I was trying to entry data to my created table in oracle 11g express edition command line using the insert command but as soon as  I closed the window that is the command line all the data I entered got erased

[image: pic after entering data]

[image: pic after closing the window]

Comment: screen shots of command sessions are _very_ difficult to read. Nothing prevents you from simply copying the text from the command window and pasting it - _formatted_ into your question.  That said, I'd agree with the other respondent - you forgot to COMMIT after your insert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must make commit after insert to make your changes visible for other sessions.